# Add values and join rows on condition in a Mysql query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, window-functions

I have a table with time-in/time-out data in a structure as shown below.

| id | date | timein | timeout | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2024-01-02 | 01:00 | 02:00 | 01:00 |
| 3 | 2024-01-02 | 02:30 | 07:00 | 04:30 |
| 3 | 2024-01-02 | 09:00 | 09:10 | 00:10 |
| 3 | 2024-01-02 | 09:10 | 09:30 | 00:20 |
| 3 | 2024-01-02 | 12:00 | 12:25 | 00:25 |

Time-in positions with a duration less than 30 minutes should not be considered for calculation. however, if two consecutive time-in for a day is more than or equal to 30 minutes then it should be considered. like in the above example, row 3 time-out is same as row 4 time-in 09:00-09:10/09:1--09:30. they are considered as single time-in and should be added if their total time is greater than 30 minutes.
I came up with the following query to get the day wise total duration excluding durations less than 30 minutes but not including the time-in duration as explained above.

```
SELECT
    DATE,  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))),'%H:%i' ) AS total,
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)) AS seconds
FROM
    `timeintable`
WHERE
    id = '3' AND( DATE BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-10') AND(TIME_TO_SEC(duration) >= 1800)
GROUP BY
    DATE
ORDER BY
    DATE ASC
```

Is it possible to achieve the same through SQL query rather than php array loop? My attempt using LEAD/LAG functions were unsuccessful.

Comment: *however, if two consecutive time-in for a day is more than or equal to 30 minutes then it should be considered.* Does these timeranges must be adjacent? I.e. if in 4th row the times are 9:11-9:31 then this row should not be combined with row 3 and the combined value should not be taken into account? Also - if more than 2 consecutive timeranges gives 30 min or more whereas any 2 of them are less (9:00-9:10, 9:10-9:20, 9:20-9:30) does these rows should be counted?

Comment: What is MySQL version **precisely**? `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: @Akina it should be considered only when they are adjacent. If the time-out time is equal to the time-in time of next row on same day. More than two consecutive rows satisfying above condition should also be considered for checking if greater than 30 minutes.
MySQL version is 10.6.16-MariaDB-cll-lve.

Comment: *MySQL version is 10.6.16-MariaDB-cll-lve.* MariaDB <> MySQL !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN timein = LAG(timeout) OVER (PARTITION BY id, `date` ORDER BY timein)
                 THEN 0 
                 ELSE 1
                 END not_adjacent  
  FROM test
-- WHERE id IN ( {needed ids list} )
--   AND `date` IN ( {needed dates list} )
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT *,
         SUM(not_adjacent) OVER (PARTITION BY id, `date` ORDER BY timein) group_no
  FROM cte1
  ),
cte3 AS (
  SELECT id, `date`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(timein), MAX(timeout)) duration
  FROM cte2
  GROUP BY id, `date`, group_no
  HAVING duration >= TIME_TO_SEC('00:30:00')
  )
SELECT id, `date`, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(duration)) daily_duration
FROM cte3
GROUP BY id, `date`
```

step-by-step [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kIl40yrd) with some comments.

Comment: Thank you @Akina. When I test it , I get the error like 'Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: '18:30'" probably because time-in and timeout are saved as VARCHAR in my table.

Comment: @ShahabMohd *time-in and timeout are saved as VARCHAR* Adjust `cte1` and perform correct convertion (CAST) from VARCHAR to TIME (also - replace an asterisk with definite columns names and perform the convertion for them too). PS. Next time - always provide a sample of your table as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, not as table-formatted text.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that